# How to use .each method @ table td where td has class and also put the text in it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I want merge the all td where classname='blahblah'

Here is my Html Code:

```
<table><tbody><tr>
            <th>Single Room</th>
            <th>101</th>
            <td class="blahblah"></td>
            <td class="blahblah"></td>
            <td class="blahblah"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>Single Room</th>
            <th>102</th>
            <td class="blahblah"></td>
            <td class="blahblah"></td>
            <td class="blahblah"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr></tbody></table>
```

this is my jquery that i am using to put the text in one td.

Please let me know how can i do this 
     $("tbody").find("tr").each(function() {

```
                //merge and put the text to All merged TD's
                $(this).find('td.blahblah').text('hi'); 

             });
```

Please help me how we can do this.

Comment: Please find a better explanation. First you want to merge (which means remove all of them and replace them with only one instance). Then you show code to have the same text for all td elements with class "blahblah"

Comment: okey that fine but how to do that?

Comment: Ok ... for starters: Please confirm if you want to do this: Remove all td with class "blahblah" which are in the same row(!) and add one new td with this class in the same row. Its text content should be the concatenated text content of the "old" td (the ones being removed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I've understood what you're trying to do correctly, you can get all the `td.blahblah` elements, remove all but the first (see [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/), [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)) and then set the text in the one left:

```
$("tbody").find("tr").each(function() {
    //merge and put the text to All merged TD's
    $(this).find('td.blahblah').not(":first").remove().end().text('hi');
});​
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/s47kE/1/).

Comment: HI James thnx for this help..? I have one more question if you don't mind. How to create div over the selected td's the table can be, i don't how much row it contain may be it can be 100 rows. now i want to put div over the selected td..same like you did there but not want to remove td and not want to merge the td's

Comment: @RahulKumar - I'm not very clear what you want. It's probably better to write a proper new question, with some code, so everyone can see it and try to answer.